# Laravel - how do you access App object in a custom class?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom class in app/libraries/data/Data.php where i want to return a connection to a database.

The problem is i need to dynamically load a database that doesn't(and can't) exist in the config file.

I found a nice solution, and to be honest it was exactly what i was hoping for, but it seems i cant access the App object from there.

```
<?php
namespace libraries\data;
use DB;

class Data 
{

    public function db($name, $firma = false)
    {

        if ($name == 'firma') {

            $config = App::make('config');
            $connections = $config->get('database.connections');

            $newConnection = $connections[$config->get('database.firma_%s')];

            $name = sprintf('firma_%s', $firma);
            $newConnection['database'] = $name;

            App::make('config')->set('database.connections.'.$name, $newConnection);
        }

        return DB::connection($name);
    }
}
?>
```

Update: of course i tried "use App;" (d`oh) and of course it didn't work. And of course it works now.

Answer (score 10):

You could also use the `app()` helper function which returns the application instance. And `$config = app('config');` to get the config object.

Answer (score 5):

Your are in the namespace `libraries\data`. Either you add `use App;` or you call the App methods with `\App::`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you define a custom namespace *libraries\data* , the application will try to find the App class in the libraries\data namespace.

If you want to use the laravel App class you need to write this:

```
 $config = \App::make('config');
```

Or add `use App;` at the top of your file like you did with the DB class.